# Trying to get property 'sub_cat_name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

**The error that I'm getting:**

`Trying to get property 'sub_cat_name' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\E-commerce\resources\views\frontend\productreview.blade.php)`

**The controller:**

```
public function product_view($id)
{
    $subcat = SubCategory::get();
    $data = DB::select('SELECT
                        sub_category.sub_cat_name, category.cat_name, product_images.prdt_image, product.prdt_name, product.actual_price, product.prdt_decription, product.id
                        FROM product
                        INNER JOIN category ON
                        product.catid = category.id
                        INNER JOIN product_images ON
                        product.id = product_images.prdt_id
                        INNER JOIN sub_category ON
                        product.sub_cat_id = sub_category.id
                        WHERE product.id=?', [ $id ]);

    return view("frontend.productreview", [
        'data' => $data,
        'subcat' => $subcat
    ]);
}
```

The SQL is obviously written in one line, but I changed it for readability purposes.

**Blade template:**

```
@foreach ($data as $prdt_data)
    <div class="pd-title">
        <span>{{ $prdt_data->sub_cat_name }}</span>
        <h3>{{ $prdt_data->prdt_name }}</h3>
        <a href="#" class="heart-icon">
            <i class="icon_heart_alt"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pd-rating">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
        <span>(5)</span>
     </div>
     <div class="pd-desc">
        <p>{{ $prdt_data->prdt_decription }}</p>
        <h4>{{ $prdt_data->actual_price }}<span>629.99</span></h4>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Too much of this post is actually code and because of that I need to write this line. Please ignore it.

Comment: var_dump the $subcat and see what it holds. It's (probably) an array

Comment: use array to access data

Comment: Do you have any question about all that code?

Comment: Please keep the SQL on separate lines in your code, you need to be able to read it too lol it will work just the same